# Altium trace symmetry

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, design, trace, breakout

I am designing a board and the traces look like this:
[image]

Is there any hotkey to make the traces be similar? I.e. the vertical lengths are uniformly varying, the distance between the diagonal tracks is equal etc.

Essentially I want to make tidy tracks. I can do it manually, but is there any quick way to do something like this? I usually use edit-> align to do similar spacing horizontally or vertically, but this is a bit different since there is a diagonal part to the tracks.

Thanks

Comment: CTRL-RIGHT CLICK on the 'middle' (angled) segments one by one such that you 'select' them all.   Then hit SHIFT-CTRL-H.    They'll all be perfectly spaced between the left & right extremes.  Manually doing up the rest of it will be easy after that.   Try it.  You can always CTRL-Z if you don't like it  ;)

Answer (score 1):

I normally just fiddle with them until it looks right, but then, I'm like that...

Some things that can help:

- Get in the habit of changing origins and grids.  This can be done with E, O, S and G, G.  (Just don't lose track of your original origin, :) choose an obvious point like a corner, or place a center mark or something you can come back to.)  While this won't save you the trouble of touching each trace, you can snap them to the desired spacing with minimal action.  Something like, set origin to a trace or corner (elbow) or pin, set grid to pitch, and line them all up one grid space apart (or two or whatever).
- You could probably set up arrays of traces beforehand.  For example, if you lay a diagonal trace, rubber-stamp (CTRL+R) a row of them, now you've got basically a patch of cross-hatching, but it's free floating track objects.  Select the row of pins (CTRL+drag), go to PCB List, sort by X1 or Y1 (X in this case), and copy net names.  Select the traces, sort again by direction, then paste net names.  Move the diagonal traces between the two rows of pins.  They will overlap and intersect (and automatically cut) the existing (straight vertical) traces (which you'd leave long beforehand).  Select carefully and delete the excess.

I've never done the latter before, but, maybe I should, it seems pretty feasible.

There's also multiroute (select objects from multiple nets, P, M*), though it tends to have ugly results when you try and finish a route (CTRL+click), or if there's just a few obstacles.  And "worst" of all, the diagonals won't be snapped to grid; horror of horrors. :)

*Oh, they changed the bind for this in AD20 or so, didn't they?  The equivalent then, of course.  And maybe ActiveRoute doesn't do too bad in some places.

I'm also fond of fiddling around like this,

[image: Angled bus with stairstep routing]

which at least can be rubber-stamped once I get a few steps going.  It's still triangular effort though (i.e. for every Nth pin being hugged, add N pieces to the structure; total pieces go as O(pins^2)).

Comment: You can also set up user definable grids. See [Altium documentation](https://www.altium.com/documentation/altium-designer/pcb-grids-system#!user-definable-grids).

Comment: @qrk Yup, of which custom (global) grid is just the start; you can set rectangular (i.e. unequal) axes, by region, and even polar coordinates. Way more bother than is worth for just setting up a pretty bus, but can alleviate a lot of annoyance say when routing lots of connections between parts with different (off-grid) pitches. (Which my image also somewhat illustrates: the odd spacing between test points and vias. Gah!)

Answer (score 0):

The traces should be straight lines between each pair of pads. You’ll have a nice looking fan without having to align anything. There’s no point to this 90-45 layout when doing such pitch-adapting connections. It adds unnecessary complexity to the layout.

[image: Example of a straight-through connection between connectors of two different pitches]